# Free Jqgrid and custom formatter checkbox

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

When I click at last column checkbox, nothing happens.

```
//$.fn.jqm = false;
$.jgrid.jqModal = $.jgrid.jqModal || {};
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.jqModal, {toTop: true});

$("#Ecran").dialog({
    //dialogClass: 'Ecran',
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 560,
    height: 370,
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/getjsonp.php?callback=?&qwery=longorders',
            mtype: "GET",
            datatype: "jsonp",
            colModel: [
                { label: 'OrderID', name: 'OrderID', key: true, width: 75 },
                { label: 'Customer ID', name: 'CustomerID', width: 150 },
                { label: 'Order Date', name: 'OrderDate', width: 150 },
                { label: 'Freight', name: 'Freight', width: 150 },
                { label:'Ship Name', name: 'ShipName', width: 150 },
                {name:'ok',index:'ok', width:60,formatter:danu_094,align:'center',search:false}
            ],
            cmTemplate: { width: 80, autoResizable: true },
            autoResizing: { compact: true },
            autoresizeOnLoad: true,
            height: "auto",
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers:true,
            //width: 480,
            height: "200",
            rowNum: 30,
            rowList:[5,10,20,30,35],
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        }).jqGrid("navGrid", { del: true, add: false, edit: false });
    },
    close:function () {}
});
$("#Ecran").dialog("open");

function danu_094 (val, options){
  idrow=options.rowId;
  var checked=(val == 'T') ? "checked='checked'" : "";
  return '<input type="checkbox"' + checked  + ' value="'+ val+ '" id='+ 'prel_'+idrow+' onchange="senddata_094('+idrow+')" /> ';
}

function senddata_094 (id){  //alert(id);
  idelem=$('#prel_'+id);
  if ((idelem).is(':checked'))   idelem.val('T');
  else idelem.val('F');
  var sqldate = "&id="+id+"&preluat="+idelem.val();
  alert(sqldate);
}
```

For demo please see http://jsfiddle.net/9ezy09ep/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you want to do with the code. In any way it contains many errors. For example you use

```js
function danu_094 (val, options){
  idrow=options.rowId;
    var checked=(val == 'T') ? "checked='checked'" : "";
    return '<input type="checkbox"' + checked  + ' value="'+ val+ '" id='+ 'prel_'+
        idrow+' onchange="senddata_094('+idrow+')" /> ';
}
```

where variable `idrow` is not declared. You should use `" checked='checked'"` instead of `"checked='checked'"`.

The next problem: `senddata_094` which you use needed be defined as global function. So you have to use for example

```js
window.senddata_094 = function (id) {
    ...
}
```

or

```js
senddata_094 = function (id){
    ...
}
```

where `senddata_094` in not defined.

instead of

```js
function senddata_094 (id){
    ...
}
```

The next problem: you use `idelem` variable inside of `senddata_094`.

By the way you can change `' onchange="senddata_094('+idrow+')" /> '` to `' onchange="senddata_094.call(this,'+idrow+')" /> '`. It will initialize `this` inside of `senddata_094` to the checkbox. You can use `$(this)` instead of `$('#prel_'+id)` in the `senddata_094` function. Thus you will don't need to set any `id` attribute on the checkbox.

In the same you don't need to set any `onchange` attribute at all. Instead of that you can define `change` event on the grid level. The event handler will be called because of event bubbling:

```js
$("#jqGrid").bind("change", function (e) {
    var rowid = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
    alert("changed id=" + rowid);
});
```

Comment: In old version 4.7.0 this code was ok, but in free jqgrid, when click on the checkbox does not work. checkbox not active but not dezactive.

Comment: @DavidO.: You should clear formulate your question. What the code should do? You posted the code where `onchange` didn't executed at all because it was defined as *local function* . What you mean under "checkbox not active"? I don't see that it is disabled. Do you want that the checkox stay checked after the click? Sorry, but asking short questions you save your time, but spend my time. Could you formulate your questions more clear?

Comment: Yes i want checked after the click or unchecked after change click.

Comment: @DavidO.: Thank you for the bug reporting. I tested the code and found the reason: [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/ff65140bdda91961faee1da6884dd18218372c89) which I made recently. I reverted [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/674e2b51c2a8e7fdbdd1079667bdb223a6693d69). You should refresh the code which you use from github. Please describe your questions more exactly in the future. It could save many my time.

Comment: The same thing happens to jqgrid, when use of multiselect: true option. the rows is selected on click , but not deselected on change .

Comment: @DavidO.: Sorry, do you want report one more bug? Do you mean the problem in the current version of free jqGrid? Or you mean some old version of jqGrid? If you know some problem in free jqGrid, please describe the exact test case which can be used to reproduce the problem. I want to fix all known bugs before publishing release 4.9.

Comment: Problem is in the curent version of free jqgrid. If i use option multiselect:true of jqgrid and click on checkbox cb_jqgrid, the rows is selected, but at deselected cb_jqgrid, the rows dont deselected.

Comment: @DavidO.: Thank you! Now I see the problem. It's almost the same problem as you reported. I posted [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/6bf5ec523d1a5ba13e0275abe733eb79cc52d928) on github. Do you know some more problems? All bug reports are welcome!